# Text Based Adventure Structure Recommendations

Tags: java, object, structure, adventure

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm trying to write a text based adventure.

I'm using Java and I want to develop a class structure.  Currently, I have a character object, room objects, and a location driver.  The character's location and inventory are in the character object.  The location driver instantiates room objects as required.  (ie, Character chooses to move from Room A to B, the location driver instantiates room B, the moves the character to Room B, and then the room B prompt begins)  Each room has prompts, inventory, and exits.

It's working alright, except the location driver runs an if function that matches the room code to a specific room function (ie, Room C function).  Inside the function, the details of the room are filled.  Then the room is instantiated with the characteristics.

Is there a better way to do this?  I mean, it works. But it feels painfully hamfisted.

Should I just instantiate all the rooms at once?  Or is there a better overall structure?

Comment: There are many ways to do this; it winds up being an opinion question, which is probably going to be ruled Out Of Scope for StackOverflow. The one suggestion I'd make is that you probably want tables rather than your if statements.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but does feel OT - where *should* such types of questions go?